Cucumeber Bdd Giving Step Implementation error in cypress
Iam trying to run feature file in cypress but every time it gives step implementation error i have tried all the processes but it doesn't resolve the issue
image 1 
image 2 
Iam trying to run the feature file but it doesn't resolve this error,i have configured cypress.js file and package .js file but still no progress

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
